# Error envio de Correo con la funcion MAIL desde LAMPP- ubuntu

Tags: php, email

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo donde envio correo electronicos desde mi pagina  web hacia el correo de una cliente en este caso es uno mio pero en si la verdad no entiendo antes cuando lo usaba funcionaba correctamente sin problemas, pero de una dia para otro no funciona??

noo actualize ni el sistema ni el LAMPP estoy en ubuntu de escritorio

alguien sabe porque la verdad no entiendo si antes funcionaba correctamente.

puse todo el codigo en mismo archivo para que lo vean bien: -->

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "gilbertoquintero656@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Este es un mensaje de prueba. " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Gracias se envio tu Correo con exito " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que error te da ? Piensa que hay muchos servidores de correo que no aceptan recibir mensajes de direcciones IPs dynámicas, o que no sean servidores de correo convenientemente configurados.

Comment: NetVicious ya encontre el error era porque lo ejecutaba en LAMPP y Apache en si mismo me lo bloqueada, porque ? la verdad no tengo idea porque cuando analizada el trafico que salia de mi computadora apache soltaba un error en el puerto cuando ejecutaba esa funcion, me dijieron que tenia que configurar el LAMPP, pero la verdad me deje de cosas y lo subi a un servidor de prueba en mi caso hostinger y funcion correctamente.

Comment: Para el envío de correos desde PHP se recomienda utilizar siempre PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) ya que así no dependes de la configuración del Apache que en algunos entornos no te dejan modificar. Además esa librería te evita problemas de inyección de cabeceras en los correos, problema que tu código parece tener en el campo $from.